# Installing Softwares on modern.ie VMs

Tags: virtual-machine, modern.ie

I've to use Windows for a college course and I was thinking of getting the Modern.ie VMs. However, before going for the massive download, I want to ascertain whether or not it actually contains a full Windows- meaning can I install softwares (compilers, editors, etc.) in the VMs or do they, somehow, boot directly into IE or something (knowing MS, anything is possible).
I know about 90-day restriction; the course is shorter, fortunately. Also, I'm running Arch Linux on a 64 bit machine, if it matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VM's are full copies of Window. Though technically they are only meant to be used for IE testing, there aren't many modification from a clean install of Windows with updates applied. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2013/12/18/ie11-virtual-machines-now-available-on-modern-ie.aspx) for an overview.